# BlackBerry Packager for Android Error - An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Today I decided to repackage, sign and publish my Android app to the Windows platform using the 'BlackBerry Packager for Android'. https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/app-signing-bar-creation

However it doesn't seem to work and I get the following error:

> We're sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. The
>   information has been registered and we're working on getting this
>   fixed as soon as we can.

I have searched online and there seems to be no answer for this.

Has anyone experienced this issue or knows how I can resolve it?

Thanks a million,
Sarah.

Comment: Solution: I used this online tool to convert my apk file to .bat http://apk2bar.unker.net/ , highly recommend it, then I uploaded to the blackberry store for approval